I am running a python code of module-pox and having an error:No module named pox.core.pox version=0.3.4 and python=3.10.12?Guide please
from pox.core import core
from pox.lib.util import dpidToStr
import pox.openflow.libopenflow_01 as of
from pox.openflow.of_json import *
from pox.lib.recoco import Timer


Error:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pox.core'

python version=3.10.12
Can anyone guide?

I installed pox using pip install pox
pox version=0.3.4
But error is not resolved.

Take a look to this answer . it usually a problem of where the package was installed
